# Class Slim not found when installing slim with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I followed the instruction on slim framework. Created a composer.json file in my directory

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "2.*"
    }
}
```

and run composer install file. I have the following directory structure now

[image]

As described in the documentation at slim framework i created an index.php file and require the vendor/autoload.php

But i am getting Class not found error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **namespaces** when instantiating classes ... like so `new \Slim\Slim();`.

Comment: there was already index.php in vendor directory i deleted that and now its working fine. thanks